# Hadoop mapreduce example documentation

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Where can I find detailed documentation for the example programs mentioned below, I am unable to find this in the documentation.

```
hduser@canberra:~/work/software/cloudera/hadoop-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0$ hadoop jar src/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/target/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.0.0-cdh4.0.0.jar 
An example program must be given as the first argument.
Valid program names are:
  aggregatewordcount: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
  aggregatewordhist: An Aggregate based map/reduce program that computes the histogram of the words in the input files.
  bbp: A map/reduce program that uses Bailey-Borwein-Plouffe to compute exact digits of Pi.
  dbcount: An example job that count the pageview counts from a database.
  distbbp: A map/reduce program that uses a BBP-type formula to compute exact bits of Pi.
  grep: A map/reduce program that counts the matches of a regex in the input.
  join: A job that effects a join over sorted, equally partitioned datasets
  multifilewc: A job that counts words from several files.
  pentomino: A map/reduce tile laying program to find solutions to pentomino problems.
  pi: A map/reduce program that estimates Pi using a quasi-Monte Carlo method.
  randomtextwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random textual data per node.
  randomwriter: A map/reduce program that writes 10GB of random data per node.
  secondarysort: An example defining a secondary sort to the reduce.
  sort: A map/reduce program that sorts the data written by the random writer.
  sudoku: A sudoku solver.
  teragen: Generate data for the terasort
  terasort: Run the terasort
  teravalidate: Checking results of terasort
  wordcount: A map/reduce program that counts the words in the input files.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no separate documentation for all the examples. So, code is the only source of information.

First, the association between the valid program names (distbbp) and the java class (o.a.h.examples.pi.DistBbp) have to be found from [ExampleDriver.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/ExampleDriver.java). The actual code ([o.a.h.examples.pi.DistBbp](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/examples/pi/DistBbp.java)) in most of the cases have the parameters to be sent and their description in the comments, if not go through the code.